# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.Malformed)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto3

Any suggestion pls, Here is the code, works fine if i call function as get_instance_name ('i-0368cdfdded') and error i get is

Tried ids.txt as both 'i-xxxx' or i-xxx

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.Malformed) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: Invalid id: "i-xxxxxx"

```
import boto3
AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"
AWS_PROFILE = "profilex"
session=boto3.session.Session(profile_name=AWS_PROFILE)
ec2 = session.resource('ec2', region_name=AWS_REGION)

def get_instance_name(fid):
    i = ec2.Instance(fid)
    instancename = ''
    for tags in i.tags:
        if tags["Key"] == 'Name':
            instancename = tags["Value"]
    return instancename

with open('ids.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        get_instance_name ('line')
```

Answer (score 0):

so what i found is i get expected output when i run the program in interactive python terminal but not run as program. I am not able to figure that out why, but the program itself works on console. Here is what i ran last which worked. (  I was doing many trial & errors )

```
import boto3
import sys
import os
import json
AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"
AWS_PROFILE = "xxxx"
session=boto3.session.Session(profile_name=AWS_PROFILE)
ec2 = session.resource('ec2', region_name=AWS_REGION)

def get_instance_name(fid):
    i = ec2.Instance(fid)
    instancename = ''
    for tags in i.tags:
        if tags["Key"] == 'Name':
            instancename = tags["Value"]
    return instancename

filename="xxx.txt"
with open(filename) as file:
  while (line := file.readline().rstrip()):
    #print(line)
    get_instance_name(line)
```